# ActiveRecord - How to `select` polymorphic join as a boolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I've been banging my head against the wall attempting to come up with this query, so I figured it was time that I post here.

I have a class called `Flair` -- it's polymorphic, since lots of things can have Flair:

```
class Flair < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flairable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And a `Comment` has many `Flairs`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flairs, as: :flairable
end
```

When getting a list of Comments, I also want to know which ones have a Flair that belongs to a given user.

The best I've been able to come up with so far is

```
# don't worry about the interpolation; just for the example
# and assume we have valid @comments and user_id
  @comments.select('comments.*').
    select('flairs.id as has_flaired').
    joins("left join flairs on flairable_id = comments.id and flairs.user_id = #{user_id}")
```

But this returns one result for every Flair on the Comment (as expected from a left join), effectively multiplying the number of appearances of each Comment in the array by the number of flairs it has.

I've tried using `distinct on (user_id)`, applying a `limit`, etc., but those efforts only turn up syntax errors.

Can anyone offer any guidance? Especially useful would be a pointer to somewhere in the docs that has examples a bit more involved than the ones offered here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html. I've also tried the suggestions at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html, but nothing seems to stick.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try rewording the description of `user_has_thought`? I cannot parse it. :(

Comment: Sure -- reading it over, not sure how I thought it was clear. I'll update the question to more accurately reflect the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 7.2.1.3 in www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html and the first example [here](https://www.periscope.io/blog/4-ways-to-join-only-the-first-row-in-sql.html), and an extremely patient boss ended up helping most with this problem. In the end (after banging on the keyboard for a while), I finally managed to please the Postgres/ActiveRecord gods with a syntactically correct query (we're sanitizing `user_id` before passing it to the `joins` statement.

```
@comments.select(
  "comments.*,
   flairs.id as has_flaired"
).joins(
  "left join
   flairs on flairs.id = (
     select id from flairs where flairs.user_id = #{user_id}
     and flairs.flairable_id = comments.id
     limit 1
   )"
)
```

This works because I'm only interested in whether or not a row with that user and flairable_id exists in the flairs table, so we just check the table in a subquery and use the results in the main query.

It makes sense now that I've written it out, but I'll leave this here in case anyone else gets similarly flummoxed.